# Cloud Functions for Firebase - get data from event object in onWrite action?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a database structure like this:

```
{
  oneToOneChat:{
      chatRoomId{
           chatMessageId{
               text:...
               receiver:...
           },

           chatMessageId{
               text:...
               receiver:...
           }
       },
      chatRoomId{}
  }
}
```

whenever a message is added under any chat room, i want to get the added message so that i get the receiver id to send a notification to him

i have tried this:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/oneToOne/{pushId}')
        .onWrite(event => {
         //get message object
        //send notification
    }
```

which properties of the event object should i use to access the message object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [data properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#data). The nature of the data depends on the event type (here it is real time database event), so its a [deltasnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot).
So you can use something like

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/oneToOneChat/{pushId}')
        .onWrite(event => {
          var value = event.data.val()
        //send notification
    }
```

Also the linked Firebase documentation provides other information that you can extract from the deltasnapshot.